# I want to use regular expression in php

Tags: php, forms

I want to know how to give the user the error on form validation if `<` or `>` is used in the form fields. Here is my script:

```
$pattern = "<,>";

if (preg_match($pattern, $_POST["u"])) {
    exit("This is illegal, ERROR!!!");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[<>]`

```
if (preg_match('/[<>]/', $_POST["u"])) {
    // illegal char
}
```

However there is no need to use regular expressions. You can use strpos:

```
if (strpos($_POST["u"], '<') !== false || strpos($_POST["u"], '>') !== false) {
    // illegal char
}
```